# Custom C++ rule with the cc_common API

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to write a custom rule to compile C++ code using the cc_common API. Here's my current attempt at an implementation:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_utils.bzl", "find_cpp_toolchain")   
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/cc:action_names.bzl", "C_COMPILE_ACTION_NAME") 

def _impl(ctx):
    cc_toolchain = find_cpp_toolchain(ctx)
    feature_configuration = cc_common.configure_features(
        cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
        unsupported_features = ctx.disabled_features,
    )
    compiler = cc_common.get_tool_for_action(
        feature_configuration=feature_configuration,
        action_name=C_COMPILE_ACTION_NAME
    )
    compile_variables = cc_common.create_compile_variables(
        feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
        cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
    )
    compiler_options = cc_common.get_memory_inefficient_command_line(
        feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
        action_name = C_COMPILE_ACTION_NAME,
        variables = compile_variables,
    )

    outfile = ctx.actions.declare_file("test.o")
    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add_all(compiler_options)
    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [outfile],
        inputs = ctx.files.srcs,
        executable = compiler,
        arguments = [args],
    )

    return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([outfile]))]
```

However, this fails with the error `"execvp(external/local_config_cc/wrapped_clang, ...)": No such file or directory`. I assume this is because `get_tool_for_action` returns a string representing a path, not a File object, so Bazel doesn't add `wrapped_clang` to the sandbox. Executing the rule with sandboxing disabled seems to confirm this, as it completes successfully.

Is there a way to implement this custom rule without disabling the sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ctx.actions.run_shell` you can add the files associated with the toolchain to the input (`ctx.attr._cc_toolchain.files`). Also, you'll want to add the compiler environment variables. E.g.

```
srcs = depset(ctx.files.srcs)
tools = ctx.attr._cc_toolchain.files
...
compiler_env = cc_common.get_environment_variables(
   feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
   action_name = C_COMPILE_ACTION_NAME,
   variables = compiler_variables,
)
...
args = ctx.actions.args()
args.add_all(compiler_options)
ctx.actions.run_shell(
    outputs = [outfile],
    inputs = depset(transitive = [srcs, tools]), # Merge src and tools depsets
    command = "{compiler} $*".format(compiler = compiler),
    arguments = [args],
    env = compiler_env,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bazel doesn't add files as action inputs automatically, you have to do it explicitly, as you did in your second approach (`ctx.attr._cc_toolchain.files`). With that, `ctx.actions.run` should work just fine.

Comment: This issue was that I wasn't sure how to get from the string returned by `cc_common.get_tool_for_action` to the actual files associated with the tool  (actually, I'm still not sure how to do that - using `ctx.attr._cc_toolchain.files` seems like a hack.) I understand that the files aren't added automatically.

Comment: ctx.attr._cc_toolchain.files is the principled way to get FilesToBuildProvider from your implicit dependencies. So no need to fear that.

There is (rather unfortunate) separation between files to build from cc_toolchain and paths to those files. Ideally get_tool_for_action would return an Artifact, and a collection of related deps. We're not there now, get_tool_for_action returns a string, and actual action inputs are taken from cc_toolchain.files.